# Jquery form not saved

Tags: javascript, jquery

If a user tries to leave a page without saving it they get a message telling them.

But they also get it if they have saved the form too.

```
$("#locForm").change(function () {
    mod = 1;
});
window.onbeforeunload = function confirmExit() {
    if (mod == 1) {
        return "information not saved.";
    }
}
$("input[name='commit']").click(function () {
    mod = 0;
});
```

This is my save button:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sample btn-md reset" id="send" name="commit"><b>Save</b></button>
```

How can it only warn user if they haven't saved the form?

Comment: Why don't you set your variable at `$(form).on('submit', ...)`?

Comment: That means somehow mod is still set to 1. remove setting mod=1 and in onbeforeload - check if mod != 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong selector. Use:

```
$("button[name='commit']")
```